# how can I make the largest number zero, using special characters

Tags: javascript

I am generating the numbers from 0 to 9 with the characters "_" and "|" . I am usually able to write the numbers from 0 to 9. But I want to make the number zero a little bigger. but I do not know why the bottom part does not appear.

[image]

How can i fix it?

```
line 8-11
```

size normal of zero

```
 __ 
|  |
|__|
```

new size of zero

```
 ___  
|   |
|   |
|___|
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nwere9L6/

Comment: Cause youve just got three lines???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your string for 0 has 4 lines, and you only use 3 lines. Extract the 4th line like this:

```
line[3] += numString[3];
```

To be able to display four lines that have the same width for each digit, you'd have to add a fourth 'line' (containing 4 spaces) to each digit.

See https://jsfiddle.net/g53qx45m/1/

Comment: can you help me please with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009150/how-can-update-the-size-of-the-numbers-that-are-in-monospace-style?noredirect=1#comment82989592_48009150